# iPhone Call screen note

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to show particular note about incoming number on call screen of an iPhone.

E.g. I have Jane as a contact saved in my Contacts on an iPhone. I also have a note associated with that Jane's contact, let's say that note is "Dentist". 

Now If I get call from Jane I should be able to see "Dentist" on call screen.

I am currently using PhoneGap framework.
I have been searching for it but had no luck.

Comment: I'm afraid, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on non-jailbroken iPhone. But you can achieve it in some other way like how the sticky notes apps are working,

1. Ask the user to create a note
2. Generate a image from the user designed note(using code)
3. Finally ask the user to assign the image to the contact.

Comment: This is what I am currently thinking of doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you have no way influence how contact is displayed in phone call at not jailbroken iPhone. Information is taken from address book only.