# How to display view contact on call screen and get info comming call?

Tags: ios, iphone, screen, call

I want to display a view on call screen of iPhone and get info comming call but I can't.

I found one link access private API but it saying that apple will not approve this,

But i saw some application on appstore.

Link
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/contact-notes/id660212820?mt=8

Can any body tell me how to do this?

Comment: This might help you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597320/iphone-call-screen-note

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck using the APIs in the new [CoreTelephony](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) framework Apple added, specifically the `CTCall` class. This doesn't reveal the caller, but it may be possible to somehow get that.

**Using private APIs in any way is not recommended and will break on future releases of the OS, and it's doubtful if you'll even get in the App Store using them. Don't do it.**

It's possible that the application you cited as an example uses these private APIs, seeing as it has iOS 5 compatibility. If you really need to use that API, it's possible to obfuscate your use of it with method swizzling, or getting function pointers and calling those, although that can **will** break when Apple changes their private APIs.

Lastly, you could download and install this app, then dump its symbols to see what APIs it uses.

Comment: I doubt if apple approves app with method swizzled code .

Comment: @Kunal Balani: True, but I put that out there for completeness. I've clarified the answer in regards to private API usage.